# How do I trigger the effect of the new item, Enduring Brooch?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

According to the description in the game for the **Enduring Brooch,** it's:

> A brooch that will prevent you from going down once per battle.

But what exactly does it mean by "going down?"

Does that apply to the character that has it equipped and prevents them from being knocked out? Does that mean the if everyone is knocked out, they come back?

I had it equipped through some tough battles and the character that had it equipped still got knocked out like normal, and I still lost the battle when everyone was knocked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some tests and it seems like one of two things could happen.

- If an attack would take the equipped character's HP down to 0, it would only deal `(remaining HP - 1)` damage, taking them down to 1 instead.
  So if for example the character was at 20 HP and receives an attack that would normally deal 50 damage, they would receive at 19 damage to avoid "going down." If the character was already at 1 HP, the next attack would only deal 0 damage.
- If an attack would instantly kill the equipped character, it would leave you at 1 HP instead.

There's no indicator that the character is saved or anything, it's very subtle. So you'll want to pay attention to how much damage you're taking with that character for each kind of attack so you can determine if the effect is still available.

Answer (score 0):

"Going down" means that a characters HP reaches zero.

So the brooch effectively protects the character that has it equipped from a fatal blow once per battle.

I haven't tried it myself yet so I'm not sure if this just simply negates the attack that would deal the fatal damage or leaves your character with 1hp or similar.

In general effects on accessories are only for the character with it equipped.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to confirm, it reduces the damage dealt down such that you are left with 1 HP.